# In ruby, is there anything like using?

Tags: ruby

Some class are defined using module to create namespace. I am wondering if Ruby has the mechanism like using to use the namespace?

in CSharp, we could

```
using ****
```

How to do it in Ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want namespaces you could use ruby's modules [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Module.html) you have documentation about that.

And [here](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html) you'll find some examples to use as namespaces